# SSE program takes a lot longer on AMD than on Intel

Tags: optimization, sse

I am working in the optimization of an algorithm using SSE2 instructions. But I have run into this problem when I was testing the performance:

I) Intel e6750

1. Doing 4 times the non-SSE2 algorithm takes 14.85 seconds
2. Doing 1 time the SSE2 algorithm(processes the same data) takes 6.89 seconds

II) Phenom II x4 2.8Ghz

1. Doing 4 times the non-SSE2 algorithm takes 11.43 seconds
2. Doing 1 time the SSE2 algorithm(processes the same data) takes 12.15 seconds

Anyone can help me why this is happening? I'm really confused about the results.

In both cases I'm compiling with g++ using -O3 as flag.

PS: The algorithm doesn't use floating point math, it uses the SSE's integer instructions.

Comment: Nearly twice as long with the same binary, and on a CPU that is clocked higher and (assuming "Deneb") has the same cache size? Bummer. The only thing I could think of is if you do a lot of shuffles, since those have 3x more latency on this generation of AMD processors compared to this generation of Intel CPUs (looks different on the latest generation). Other instructions surely might have a cycle more or less here and there, but all in all it should not run 2x slower. (AMD processors are also known for "reformatting delay", but since you don't mix float/int, that shouldn't matter.)

Comment: A difference over 20% sounds strange. What's the version of the AMD Phenom? L1/L2/L3 Cache sizes? What's the algorithm implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel has made big improvements to their SSE implementation over the last 5 years or so, which AMD has not really kept up with. Originally both were really just 64 bit execution units, and 128 bit operations were broken down into 2 micro-ops. Ever since Core and Core 2 were introduced though, Intel CPUs have had a full 128 bit SSE implementation, which means that 128 bit operations effectively got a 2x throughput boost (1 micro op versus 2). More recent Intel CPUs also have multiple SSE execution units which means you can get > 1 instruction per clock throughput for 128 bit SIMD instructions.

Comment: Wow. Never thought this was so different when i bought the CPU last year =( right now i'm getting into HPC and now i can understand the money difference.

Comment: If you're using SSE then Intel is really the only game in town, for now at least. For non-SIMD code there may not be such a big difference, and Intel CPUs are pretty expensive so bang-per-buck evens out somewhat.